# River Corridor Survey Symbols for MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo

Has anyone got River Corridor Survey Symbols for MapInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the UK River Corridor Survey methodology?

Not sure the symbols exist for any GIS system. I've not seen them. You could try and create your own? This [paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0143622895000224/1-s2.0-0143622895000224-main.pdf?_tid=d8c84c8a-fae4-11e7-a008-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1516124825_0c5f926435ebeef163f11f7e2152586d) lists the symbols.

Comment: Yep that's the one. I've tried using the snipping tool and making custom symbols for them but they look terrible quality when displayed. I've resorted to overlaying multiple symbols already a part of MapInfo to make them look vaguely like the standard symbols. Would be great if someone had made them!